# Symfony2 form and Doctrine2 - creat foreign key in assigned entities fails

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm trying to add my data into my database , i was trying to not use a formbuilder, inside that i put all my form into the controller,and my entity contains a foreign key  but i got an this error :
Neither the property "id_classe" nor one of the methods "getIdClasse()", "idClasse()", "isIdClasse()", "hasIdClasse()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "MyApp\SchoolBundle\Entity\Etudiant". 
here is my function in the controller :

```
public function AjoutAction(Request $request)
{   $classe=new Etudiant();
$formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $classe);    
$formBuilder
  ->add('prenom', 'text')
  ->add('nom', 'text')
  ->add('Cin', 'integer')
  ->add('id_classe', 'integer')
  ->add('save',      'submit')
;
$form = $formBuilder->getForm();
if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
    $objToPersist = $form->getData();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($objToPersist);
    $em->flush();
} 
return $this->render('MyAppSchoolBundle:Etudiant:ajout.html.twig',array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
));
}
```

and here is my Entity

```
namespace MyApp\SchoolBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
 class Etudiant {

   /**
    * @ORM\id
    *@ORM\GeneratedValue
    *@ORM\Column(type="integer",name="ID_Etudiant")   
    */
private $Id;
/**
 *@ORM\Column{type="string",length=255}
 */
private $prenom;
/**
 *@ORM\Column{type="string",length=255}
 */

private $nom;
/**
 *@Assert\NotBlank
 *@ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true)
 */

private $cin; //unique ne fonctionne pas qu'avec les assert
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Classes",cascade={"ALL"})
 */
private $id_classe;
function getId() {
    return $this->Id;
}

function getPrenom() {
    return $this->prenom;
}

function getNom() {
    return $this->nom;
}

function setId($Id) {
    $this->Id = $Id;
}

function setPrenom($prenom) {
    $this->prenom = $prenom;
}

function setNom($nom) {
    $this->nom = $nom;
}

function getCin() {
    return $this->cin;
 }

 function setCin($cin) {
    $this->cin = $cin;
 }

public function getId_classe() {
    return $this->id_classe;
}

function setId_classe($id_classe) {
    $this->id_classe = $id_classe;
}




}
```

Comment: Work you way through the example in the manual: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html You are not understanding how Doctrine 2 manages objects.  Hint:  id_classe should just be classe and you will need to fetch the actual classe object.

Answer (score 2):

***In your form you have:***

```
 ->add('id_classe', 'integer')
```

Add a setter in your entity

```
public function setIdClasse($idClasse) {
    $this->id_classe = $idClasse;
}
```

### Edit

***Also, as a suggestion:***

<kbd>1</kbd> Always add visibility to your functions (`public function blabla()` or `private function blabla()`)

<kbd>2</kbd> Use camel case is preferred (so your properties are `$nomClasse`, `$idClasse`, `$id`, etc..)

<kbd>3</kbd> Not compulsory, but a good idea to return the object in your setter

<kbd>4</kbd> You're not very consistent in your notations (see your form builder`->add('nom', 'text')` `->add('Cin', 'integer')`)

Getters and Setter would normally look like this:

```
public function getNomClasse() 
{
    return $this->nomClasse;
}

public function setNomClasse($nomClasse) 
{
    $this->nomClasse = $nomClasse;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: sorry i put the wrong entity can u check the new one please

Comment: THANK you but after modificatio  i got this error :Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given in C:\wamp\www\HelloWordExemple\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 1602

Comment: I would open a new question for that as this might confuse other people who have the same issue.